# Loading a PDF file into a program using a tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pdf, tkinter, nltk

The program I am writing is able to take in a PDF, find all the non-stop words in the PDF, display all of those words in a table as well as how often they appeared in the PDF, and then display that table in a web browser. So far, the program has been able to execute this when the PDF that is being read is located in the same file as the program that is being executed. I want to make my code more stream-lined, so a user can decide what PDF the program will read, regardless of where the PDF actually is. To do this, I attempted to use tkinter, because all other GUI are unavailable for me to use, and I can get the window and the buttons necessary to appear, as well as the file explorer to open, however I can't figure out how to actually have the code exectue when I "double-click" the PDF I want the code to read.

```
import word_bag_GUI
import PyPDF2
import pandas
import webbrowser
import os
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#Method that a pdf that is read into the program goes through to eliminate any unwanted words or symbols#
def preprocess(text):
    #Filters out punctuation from paragraph witch becomes tokenized to words and punctuation#
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    result = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #Makes all words lowercase#
    words = [item.lower() for item in result]

    #Removes all remaining tokens that are not alphabetic#
    result = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]

    #Imports stopwords to be removed from paragraph#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    #Removes the stop words from the paragraph#
    filtered_sent = []
    for w in result:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(w)

    #Return word to root word/chop-off derivational affixes#
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for w in filtered_sent:
        stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

    #Lemmatization, which reduces word to their base word, which is linguistically correct lemmas#
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_words = ' '.join([lem.lemmatize(w,'n') and lem.lemmatize(w,'v') for w in filtered_sent])

    #Re-tokenize lemmatized words string#
    tokenized_word = word_tokenize(lemmatized_words)
    return tokenized_word

#Loads in PDF into program#
PDF_file = word_bag_GUI.open_PDF
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

#Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
doc_content = ""

#Extract text from the PDF file#
for i in range(number_of_pages):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    doc_content += page_content

#Turns the text drawn from the PDF file into data the remaining code can understand#
tokenized_words = preprocess(doc_content)

#Determine frequency of words tokenized + lemmatized text#
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
final_list = fdist.most_common(len(fdist))

#Organize data into two columns and export the data to an html that automatically opens#
df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ["Word", "Frequency"])
df.to_html('word_frequency.html')
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('word_frequency.html'))

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.resizable(0,0)
window.title("Word Frequency Program")

#Browse through file directory and select PDF to be used in code#
def open_PDF():
    filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("PDF files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Browse Files", command = open_PDF)
button1.grid()

#Quits out of the program when certain button clicked#
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Quit Program", command = window.quit)
button2.grid()

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

I expected the program to execute the same way before I implemented a tkinter GUI, printing out a table with the words and frequency in a web browser, however when I select and open the PDF I want the program to read, nothing happens.

Edit: I seem to have gotten some portion of it to work, however now I'm getting an exception which states:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Edit 2: I am now getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has not attribute 'seek'
```

and the only change I have made was changing the open_PDF() method as such:

```
def open_PDF():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("PDF files","*.pdf"), ("all files","*.*")))
    return filename
```

Comment: It is because the statement `PDF_file = word_bag_GUI.open_PDF` will assign the function reference to `PDF_file` function, but not the result of the function you expected.

Comment: @acw1668 so how would I go about executing the word_bag_extraction_program after selecting the file that I want to be executed (if that makes sense)? My thought proces last night is that I could use another tkinter button to execute a different method when clicked that would cause the word_bag_extraction program to execute. (I hope that makes sense, I'm new to all the coding jargon and python in general)

Comment: @acw1668 in more simple terms, how would I assign the result of the function to PDF_file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the PDF to load into the program correctly and appear in the browser. I only had to change two small bits of code in both programs. For the first bit, I changed the open_PDF function to this:

```
def select_PDF():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
    return filename
```

Then I changed the "Load PDF into program" portion of code to this:

```
filepath = word_bag_GUI.select_PDF()
PDF_file = open(filepath, 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)
```

So I was able to get that to execute properly, however now two directory windows appear instead of one, so that is an issue I will work out now.